# Installing wkhtmltopdf linux cPanel server

Tags: linux, installation, cpanel, wkhtmltopdf, shared-hosting

I'm trying to install wkhtmltopdf on a server to use on my website. The server is a shared hosting server from cPanel and uses linux. This means I don't have root access. I do have ssh access. I tried several things but I cannot seem to get it to work. What I tried is:

wget https://github.com/wkhtmltopdf/wkhtmltopdf/releases/download/0.12.4/wkhtmltox-0.12.4_linux-generic-amd64.tar.xz (it's a 64-bit, and this works)

Then to extract the tar I use:
tar -xvf wkhtmltox-0.12.4_linux-generic-amd64.tar.xz

I then get an error saying: 
tar: This does not look like a tar archive 
tar: Skipping to next header 
tar: Read 1104 bytes from wkhtmltox-0.12.4_linux-generic-amd64.tar.xz 
tar: Error exit delayed from previous errors

I read online that it might be compressed or something using gzip, but that also lead to nothing. 
file  wkhtmltox-0.12.4_linux-generic-amd64.tar.xz 
gives:
wkhtmltox-0.12.4_linux-generic-amd64.tar.xz: data

Any tips are appreciated. Other methods on how to do this or ways to make this method work.

Answer (score 0):

Refer below link. Hope mentioned information will help you out .

https://www.tecmint.com/wkhtmltopdf-convert-website-html-page-to-pdf-linux/

Comment: I do not have root access so I cannot perform 'sudo' commands. Just using the command 'tar -xvf wkhtmltox-0.12.4_linux-generic-amd64.tar.xz' without the sudo gives me the errors mentioned above.

Comment: Okay but can you check whether you downloaded accurate file, In above link they mention different tar for differnt bit os (32 or 64). It might be cause.

Comment: I checked that too, I have the wrong file but still get an error

Comment: Okay so it might be because of your web server has compressed the tar file with gzip. Check here and try the solution https://superuser.com/questions/841865/extracting-a-tar-gz-file-returns-this-does-not-look-like-a-tar-archive